# Where to report bugs of R packages?

Tags: r

[Some packages](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/doRedis/index.html) do have a reference to bug reporting system, [others](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/runjags/index.html) do not. Where should I report package bugs then? **Is there any default bug reporting system for packages** which don't have their own?

I found https://bugs.r-project.org/bugzilla3/ but when I look at the [components](https://bugs.r-project.org/bugzilla3/describecomponents.cgi) it seems more like for the R core. I also tried `bug.report(package = "runjags")`, but it tried to start mail program which is not very useful.

Comment: It would be useful to read [Bug Reporting in R](https://www.r-project.org/bugs.html)

Answer (score 7):

If in doubt, send an email to the package maintainer.

```
packageDescription("thepackagename", fields = "Maintainer")
```

(This is what `bug.report` does.)

Comment: There is nothing like common bug reporting system for packages? I would like to post bugs directly somewhere instead of emailing them - to keep track of them easily in the future.

Comment: Package creators are free to use whatever system they like for hosting their development code.  github and Bitbucket are common, but many people (if they develop code at work) also use corporate repositories which may not have a publicly available bug-tracker.  So a standardised system is impossible.

Comment: I didn't mean like forcing one bugreporting system to *all* package maintainers, just something like a *default* one for those who don't have their own. I think I saw something a while ago but cannot find it.